# Android. Memory managment in different versions of Android OS

Tags: android, memory-management

I run my app on different version of Android.

In **2.2** my app uses **16** MB.
In **2.1** and **2.3.3** - **28** MB.

What difference in memory management between versions.

In my app I have enough number of pictures. Maybe this is clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, bitmaps use ARGB_8888 format in Ginerbread (2.3). So, 32 bits per pixel
By default, bitmaps use RGB_565 format in older versions (<2.3). So, 16 bits per pixel.
Hence images will take twice the amount of memory in 2.3.

This however does not explain why you have a higher memory usage in 2.1. Why don't you take a look at you hprof or do a "adb shell showmap -v 4546" where 4546 is your pid?

Comment: I know that I can use Bitmap.Config to change format of Bitmap. But i use a lot resources as Drawable or by ID. How can i control ( or set) format for this ones ?

Comment: I gonna try solve my problem using DrawableBitmap and will post result later.

Comment: It helped me to reduce some memory usage, but i'm looking for another options which specific for my app.